# JSONArray to list of objects

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have JSONArray where each element in the array is a json with 5 fields.

I would like to map this JSONArray to a list on Class objects. Each Class object has exact same fields as the json element, plus 3 additional Class fields that I would like to set to null when the object is mapped from the json element.

I tried:

```
JSONObject jsn = SomeJsonWith2Keys      
JSONArray jsn_a = (JSONArray) jsn.get("response");
List<MyClass> tags = (List<MyClass>) objectMapper.readValue(jsn_a.toString(), MyClass.class)
```

But this is throwing an exception
Cannot deserialize instance of `x.x.x.x.MyClass` out of START_ARRAY token

The array size is large and I am trying to not do mapping in a loop if possible.

I would appreciate any suggestion on how to do the mapping to the class while setting the 3 additional fields to null

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like there's some mismatch between your JSON and your class.  Since you haven't shown us either, it's impossible to say what the discrepancy is.

Comment: Which JSON API are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the type as a List rather than MyClass. You can't do this by just saying List.class, but Jackson provides a com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference class that allows you to supply the fact that you want a list of a specific type.

So assuming your objectmapper is a jackson one you can do the following.

```
List<MyClass> tags = mapper.readValue(jsn_a.toString(), new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>() {});
```

If you're OK using an array instead of a list you can specify the array type.

```
MyClass[] tags = mapper.readValue(jsn_a.toString(), MyClass[].class);
```